# innodb storage options

Tags: mysql, storage, innodb

I'm trying to figure out how to set up the storage for a site that currently requires only one server, but will certainly grow to demand more.  I the database is largely innodb tables.  I understand that clustering servers isn't an option because that ignores foreign keys.  I saw reference to federated storage, but that seems to have issues too.  Do you have any other storage suggestions that are compatible with foreign keys, and know the pros and cons?  Thanks for the help.

-Storm

Comment: What's a bc and an fk?

Comment: because and foreign key?

Comment: haha, yes.  because & foreign key

Comment: I edited the post and expanded the abbreviations so everyone can better understand the question. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [oreilly.com](http://oreilly.com/catalog/covers/9780596101718_cat.gif))</sub>

The book above is a very good place to start reading about mySQL and its various storage engines as well as the pros and cons of each.

http://oreilly.com/pub/pr/2031

Comment: ok, thanks.  im going to go pick this up asap, and try to fully understand cagenut's suggestion.

Comment: The book will help you A LOT.  You can also find/purchase it online in .PDF format I believe.

Answer (score 0):

short answer: 4 -8 spindles, 10krpm or above, raid10 w/BBU and write-back enabled

long answer: read the [book](http://oreilly.com/pub/pr/2031) and the [website](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/)